# How to provide a Map() via httr

Tags: r, httr

I have an api which calls for one of it's body to be a map, e.g.

```
{
  "functionName": "",
  "parameters": "Map[string,?]"
}
```

How do I do this with the R library httr? My instiction was to provide a nested list along the lines of

```
httr::POST(..., body = list("functionName" = "copy", "parameters" = list(a = 1, b = 2)))
```

This delivers an error, with message "Error in curl::handle_setform(handle, .list = req$fields) : 
  Unsupported value type for form field 'parameters'."

I have no real idea how to construct an object otherwise that will be accepted.

Apologies for the lack of a reprex for this question, the API is private, but hopefully my problem is simple enough that someone can find the correct syntax.

Comment: What language does the documentation for this API focus on? Are there any more details you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to this, which is to use `jsonlist::toJSON()` to construct the body. For example

```
body = jsonlite::toJSON(
    list(
      "functionName" = "Rename",
      "parameters" = (list(object = "pathtofile", 
                           newName = "myfile",
                           newExtension = ".csv")
      )), 
     auto_unbox = TRUE
)
```

This constructs a json object in the expected format, which I don't think httr can do on it's own.